# Receiving datetime in UTC but need it in eastern standard time

Tags: javascript

I'm importing a date/time from a server (in UTC) and need to display it for the user in EST.  What I'm doing:

```
value = data['eTime.1']
```

which pulls the date/time over with the result (example):  `2021-04-01 11:02:55`

I just need it in eastern standard time (preferably without seconds).

Comment: this is unclear, you mean : you receive a **string value** from a server that represente an UTC (meridian ZERO) Value ?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: What do you mean by EST ? Est of China ? or Europe ?

Comment: Sorry EST = eastern standard time (US)

Comment: Mister Jojo - I'm sorry.  I think its a string value(?).  To elaborate further.  One program collects data and is trying to talk to the 2nd program (which I have access to).  It sends all the data over in an array and I can pull the pieces that I want to have them show in a field. That's what I'm doing here but the data is in UTC time instead of Eastern Standard Time (US).  Does that help at all?

Comment: UTC times always indicate their time zone (which is a meridian). The example time you suggest does not indicate one; it is not UTC. Does the time indicated correspond to the date / time of your server? in this case, what is his TZ?

Comment: eastern standard time (US)  is depreciated, is there a daylight saving time to consider?

Answer (score 0):

This question is slightly unclear as Mister Jojo has already said. UTC is a standard system while EST is a timezone. If you want a very accurate answer we will  need more information, but for the quick and dirty answer it would look like this (assuming you mean this date is UTC-0):

```
let betterDateString = value.replaceAll('-', ' ') + " GMT";
let date = new Date(value);
console.log((new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {timeStyle: "full", timeZone: "America/New_York"})).format(date));
```

If you are already in EST, then the time will be converted automatically for you when you construct the Date object. If you want a more accurate answer than this, you should look into a library to handle it for you because it is a rabbit hole of madness to support timezones.

Comment: Thank you for taking a crack at this.  I'm very sorry I couldn't make it more clear.  I'm still learning and very much a novice at JS.  I did manage to get a solution figured out. 
value = new Date(data['eTimes.03']+ " UTC");

Comment: @paintrn  The UTC system is a universal standard for writing a date-time information, it has nothing to do with mastering JS.

Comment: No problem, time is probably one of the most annoying corner case plagued topics with any programming language.